# First Day of Next Year for SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

This should not be this hard.  I simply need the following:

```
SET @DueDate = CONVERT (DATETIME, '01/01/2010')
```

However, I need it pragmatically so that if it were March of 2010, the date given would be '01/01/2011'.

I know it's simple, but my brain isn't coming up with it.  I'm sure it's with a DateAdd and `getdate()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Number of year boundaries between now and year zero less one (31 dec 1899), add back on.

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Let's try a date next year to get 2011. because 1 Jan 2010 is start of next year in 2009...

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, -1, '2010-03-21'), 0)
```

Comment: Actually, that returns '1/2/2010'.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Database Journal article: [How to Calculate Different SQL Server Dates](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3076421/Examples-of-how-to-Calculate-Different-SQL-Server-Dates.htm):

**First Day of the *Next* Year**

I use the year interval (yy) to display the first day of the *next* year.

> select DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, -1, getdate()), 0)

Comment: Thank you, but shouldn't that be: 
select DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, -1, getdate()), 0) 
same as above for next year?

Comment: Yes. As posted, it was the first day of *this* year. I will make the change.

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, with SQL 2012 you can do `DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@date) + 1, 1, 1)`.  In your case, `DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1, 1, 1)`

Hat tip to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13873750/155892

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, create a table with first of the year dates, then pick the smallest that is larger than your date.

Perhaps simply put a string together, '01/01' + (MyYear + 1)?

Answer (score 0):

You could add one to the current year, then concat with Jan 01, then convert back to date:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), YEAR(GETDATE())+1) + '.01.01')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some parts of the examples above you could also do this. Now this assumes your acceptable date format matches M-d-yyyy.

```
DATEADD(year, 1,'1-1-'+convert(varchar,DATEPART(YYYY,GetDate())))
```

Note: You get the current date, get the year part, create a string that converts to a date, then add one to the year.