# Getting start date and end date - from a given year yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

In MSSQL, Given a year 'yyyy' how would I return the starting date as 01/01/yyyy and ending date as 12/31/yyyy.

Comment: hi and welcome to stackoverflow :) what have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @yyyy int; set @yyyy = 2009;
select DATEADD(yy,@yyyy-1900,0), DATEADD(yy,@yyyy-1899,-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SQL Server 2012 (the most recent version)?

If yes, you can use the new [`DATEFROMPARTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) or [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx) functions.

Example from the first link:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS ( 2010, 12, 31 ) AS Result;
```

...will return this:

```
Result
----------------------------------
2010-12-31

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: SQL Server 2005 is what i am using

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also if you are using MySQL database;-

```
 SELECT CONCAT ('01/01','/',2009) start_date ,concat ('12/31','/',2009) end_date 
 FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
declare @yyyy int; set @yyyy = 2012;

SELECT convert(varchar,DATEADD(yyyy, @yyyy - 1900, 0), 101) AS StartDate, 
       convert(varchar,DATEADD(yyyy, @yyyy - 1899, -1), 101) AS EndDate
--OR
SELECT convert(varchar,'01/01/'+CAST(@yyyy as varchar(4)), 101) AS StartDate,
       convert(varchar,'12/31/'+CAST(@yyyy as varchar(4)), 101) AS EndDate
```

Result:

```
StartDate   EndDate
01/01/2012  12/31/2012
```